# Docker image executing golang executable: exec /usr/local/go/bin/go: exec format error

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, dockerfile

I understand that I need to specify the target platform of a `go` executable if it is supposed to run on another machine. I'm building a docker image on an apple machine with the M1 chip:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 golang:alpine AS build

WORKDIR /

ADD go.mod .
ADD go.sum .
RUN go mod download
COPY . .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -ldflags="-s -w" -o .

FROM --platform=linux/amd64 scratch

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /foo /foo

CMD ["./foo"]
```

This appears to work because inspecting the container after build outputs

```
"Architecture": "amd64",
"Os": "linux"
```

But when I now start the image on a linux server using `docker-compose`, I get an error: `exec /usr/local/go/bin/go: exec format error`

**docker-compose.yml**

```
foo:
    environment:
      - PORT=${PORT}
    image: docker.io/name/foo
    platform: linux/amd64
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    restart: always
```

I'm pretty new to docker, so I guess I'm missing something quite obvious here.

Comment: Can you provide a non-obfuscated link to your image?

Comment: Sure: https://hub.docker.com/r/chedched/foo (currently there are too many edits pending on SO, hence I had to post it here in the comments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I can confirm that you have successfully built an amd64 binary, so this isn't a `go` question.

If I run your image (on an amd64 linux system), I don't get the same error that you've reported. Given this `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
foo:
    environment:
      - PORT=${PORT}
    image: docker.io/chedched/foo
    platform: linux/amd64
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    restart: always
```

When running `docker-compose up`, I see:

```
ERROR: for images_foo_1  Cannot start service foo: failed to create shim task:
OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container
process: exec: "./foo": stat ./foo: no such file or directory: unknown
```

And this happens because you've set `WORKDIR /app`, which makes `app` the current working directory in your image, but you've installed your binary as `/foo`. You need to either:

- Change your `CMD` to reference the correct location:

  ```
  CMD ["/foo"]
  ```

  Or...
- Install the binary in `/app`:

  ```
  COPY --from=build /foo ./foo
  ```

With either of those changes, the image runs as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it! I can make the executable running with your suggested fixes locally, but not on the server. I'm using a Hetzner cloud server with a pre-installed docker image: "docker-ce-ubuntu-4gb-nbg1-1", the command "uname -a" prints "5.15.0-56-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 22 19:54:14 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux". "linux/amd64" should correctly target this platform if I understood correctly, right?

Comment: Yes, `linux/amd64` is the correct platform. I don't have access to Hetzner facilities, and your image seems correct other than the path issue, and the binary runs correctly on `x86_64` (aka `amd64`) linux systems. Since I'm not able to reproduce the problem I'm not sure I have any further ideas.

Comment: It was a very embarrassing beginner's mistake: I was under the assumption that `docker-compose up` would also pull the new images, but it does not. After running `docker-compose pull` everything worked smoothly. Thank you!